# error: conflicting types for 'functiono'

Tags: c

I know this error occurs when there is an incompatibility in the function's declaration and definition. I as far I can see in this code, the type and parameters of the function's (int getline) declaration and definition are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main() {
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }
    if (max > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", longest);
    }
    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}


void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'){
        ++i;
    }
}
```

I know I am missing something small.

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Are you on a POSIX (i.e. Linux or macOS) system, which have *another* [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function declared in `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: I am using macOS

Comment: I cannot see any declaration of "functiono" so your title is off.

Comment: the header file: `stdio.h` contains the prototype for the system function: `getline()`  so, first, change the name of your function.  The syntax for the `getline()` function is: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`, which as you can see, is not the same as your implementation of `getlline()`

Comment: regarding: `s[i] = c;`  this is assigning a 'int' to a 'char'.  so the compiler will output a warning (if compiled with `-Wconversion`)  to fix that problem, tell the compiler that you know what you are doing by using: `s[i] = (char)c;`

Comment: Any reason you don't use `fgets`?

Comment: This is one of my first code examples. I am following 'The c programming Language'. I haven't had a problem with the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX systems like linux and macos [`getline`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) is part of the standard and your
`getline` conflicts with it.

Rename your function to `mygetline`. I copied your code and rename the function,
it compiles without a problem.

Answer (score -1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. makes the minimum changes to the OPs posted code

However, the variable 'max' is never initialized to any known value   So it contains what ever trash is on the stack at its location.  The result is 1) the code will not always work and 2) it contains undefined behavior.  So the code logic needs to be corrected

Also, the posted code fails to handle the condition when the incoming line is longer than 1000 bytes.

And now, the proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int my_getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main() {
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while((len = my_getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }
    if (max > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", longest);
    }
    return 0;
}

int my_getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = (char)c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = (char)c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}


void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'){
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: one further detail.  there is no clear indication of what is to be done if multiple lines have the same (max) length?

Comment: what is the benefit of adding char in s[i] = (char)c;

Comment: It didn't make difference, It is was automatically converted for me.

Comment: @TheCaptain,  If you read the warning that the compiler outputs when it performs a implicit conversion you will notice that there is the possibility/probability of the value in the resulting 'char' array being changed.  If, instead of questioning about 'what will go wrong', and instead just tell the compiler that you know what you are doing (by including the 'cast') then you have no worry about the resulting value(s) being incorrect due to an implicit conversion

Comment: for the person that down voted the answer, be a gentleman and state (in a comment) why you down voted the answer.